# If $|G|=n>1$, then $|{\rm Aut}(G)|\le\prod_{i=0}^k(n-2^i)$ for $k=[\log_2(n-1)]$.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, logarithms, automorphism-group

This is **Exercise 1.5.16** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cprod_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5Ek(n-2%5Ei)%24%2C%20%24k%3D%5B%5Clog_2(n-1)%5D%24%2C%20group%20&p=10), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

The exercise comes with a hint:

> Use **Exercise 1.3.4.**

On page 16, *ibid.,* we have

> **Exercise 1.3.4**: Let $d(G)$ be the smallest number of elements necessary to generate a finite group $G$. Prove that $\lvert G\rvert\ge 2^{d(G)}$.

*Proof (sketch):* Each element of a minimal generating set $\{g_1,\dots, g_{d(G)}\}$ of $G$ maps to two elements in $G$: itself and its inverse (assuming they are distinct), so

$$\begin{align}
\lvert G\rvert &\ge \left\lvert \{{\rm itself}, {\rm inverse}\}^{\{g_1,\dots, g_{d(G)}\}}\right\rvert\\
&=2^{d(G)}.
\end{align}$$ "$\square$"

*(I'm aware that this sketch sweeps a lot under the rug. However, I think it illustrates the general idea.)*

### The Question:

On page 31, *ibid.*, we have

> **Exercise 1.5.16:** If  $G$ has order $n>1$, then $$\lvert {\rm Aut}(G)\rvert\le\prod_{i=0}^k(n-2^i)$$ for $k=[\log_2(n-1)]$.

### Thoughts:

Each automorphism of $G$ is determined by what it maps each of $G$'s generating elements $g_\lambda$ (as above) to. This is a key concept, I'm sure.

My first guess was that the $2^i$ in the product corresponds to $2^{d(H)}$ for $H\le G$ generated by a subset of the $g_\lambda$. I don't understand where $k$ comes from if this is the case though.

---

My postgraduate research degree specialises in combinatorial group theory, the study of groups as given by their presentations, so I feel as if I ought to be able to do this exercise without too much help, although I don't work with automorphism groups often.

---

I'm interested in understanding this exercise, in particular, because I think it's rather beautiful, especially with the value of $k$.

---

Perhaps I might have to give **Exercise 1.3.4** some more thought in order to do the exercise at hand.

---

Please help :)

Comment: I am slightly puzzled, because the argument that you are suggesting seems to prove that $|{\rm Aut}(G)| \le \prod_{i=0}^{d(G)-1} (n-2^i)$, but the previous exercise shows that $d(G) \le \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor$, so that would mean you can take $k = \lfloor \log_2(n) -1 \rfloor$, which is actually slightly stronger than what the question ask for with $k = \lfloor \log_2(n-1) \rfloor$.

Comment: For the previous exercise, I think it is cleaner to look at $\left\{\{\text{identity, itself}\}^{\{g_1,\dots,g_{d(G)}\}}\right\}$.

Comment: Yes, that's much better! Thank you, @MikeEarnest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
You are right that this exercise plays a key role. If $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ are generators of the group $G$, and $f$ is a automorphism of $G$, then $f(g_1),\ldots,f(g_k)$ are also generators of $G$. Now consider. The element $f(g_1)$ we can choose by $n-1$ ways, the element $f(g_2)$ we can choose by $n-2^1$ ways. And so on.